# Top: 100% instead of top: 0 (mathematical issue?)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using [Chris Coyier's 'long drop-down' plug-in](http://css-tricks.com/long-dropdowns-solution/) to solve my (long) dropdown problem. By the way, I'm using `top: 100%` instead of `top: 0` and because of that my dropdown menu is above the main menu.

### The Problem

[image: long drop-down example]

### The Normal Menu

[image]

[The expected](http://css-tricks.com/examples/LongDropdowns/)

The jQuery part:

```
$(function () {
            var maxHeight = $(window).height() - ($("ul.dropdown").offset().top + $("ul.dropdown").outerHeight());

            $("ul.dropdown > li").hover(function () {
                var $container = $(this),
                 $list = $container.find("ul"),
                 $anchor = $container.find("a"),
                 height = $list.height() * 1.1,       // make sure there is enough room at the bottom
                 multiplier = height / maxHeight;     // needs to move faster if list is taller

                // need to save height here so it can revert on mouseout            
                $container.data("origHeight", $container.height());

                // so it can retain it's rollover color all the while the dropdown is open
                $anchor.addClass("hover");

                // make sure dropdown appears directly below parent list item    
                $list
                    .show();

                // don't do any animation if list shorter than max
                if (multiplier > 1) {
                    $container
                        .css({
                            overflow: "hidden"
                        })
                        .mousemove(function (e) {
                            var offset = $container.offset();
                            var relativeY = ((e.pageY - offset.top) * multiplier) - ($container.data("origHeight") * multiplier);
                            if (relativeY > $container.data("origHeight")) {
                                $list.css("top", -relativeY + $container.data("origHeight"));
                            };
                        });
                }
            }, function () {

                var $el = $(this);

                // put things back to normal
                $el
                    .height($(this).data("origHeight"))
                    .find("ul")
                    .css({ top: "100%" })
                    .hide()
                    .end()
                    .find("a")
                    .removeClass("hover");
            });
        });
```

### UPDATE

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wB7fn/)

On JS Fiddle, try to change the `top:100%` of `ul.dropdown ul` rule for `top: 0` — and this is my problem.

### UPDATE v2

Removed useless content.

### UPDATE v3

Thank you everybody for the help — now I could better organize my problem.

[Look to this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wB7fn/6/) — This is my problem.

[And this is what I'm expecting](http://css-tricks.com/examples/LongDropdowns/).

Comment: If you made a JSFiddle, it'd be a lot easier to solve your problem as it may be CSS related.

Comment: You say top:100% causes your problem.  So don't use top: 100%????

Comment: And actually posting the CSS code after the words **The CSS:** may help too in debugging the CSS :D

Comment: you dont have forget one position:relative on class ?

Comment: Done! My problem is now on JsFiddle ;-) And Andrea, sorry about this — I saw that it was not necessary CSS.

Comment: @artSx If I use relative position the menu changes its width.

Comment: Setting the top to 0 does what it should, i.e. sets the top of your ul to be 0px from the top of the li that contains it. I don't get an issue on your fiddle with top: 100%.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge: If changing the 100% to 0 is your problem then don't do that... The jsfiddle that you provided doesn't seem to generate any problems of the sort you are describing...

Comment: Fellas, see my last edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the `top` rule completely will force the absolutely positioned submenu to start at the height at which the main menu elements end (which is the desired behavior). This will look the same as `top: 100%;`, but from what I understand, you want to get rid of that rule.

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/wB7fn/4/

EDIT

This is as close as I could get: http://jsfiddle.net/wB7fn/9/.

The issues with main element width had to be solved by manually extending it so that all the sub menu elements fit. Like I described in comments - the parent elements needed to have `position: relative` and appropriate `z-index`. And the last change was to make the `a` element of the main menu `display: block`, so it fills the full width of the parent `li` element.

EDIT2

Fixed the JS `top` issues here as well: http://jsfiddle.net/wB7fn/10/

Comment: Now I understand, hehe. Thanks to you, I could branch out better my problem. Look at my last edition.

Comment: Oh! Sorry! You can see now.

Comment: No problem, I'm looking at it.

Comment: You need to set relative position at parent elements and also set z-index accordingly to both the main menu and the submenu...

Comment: Of the submenu, give me a few minutes, I'll fix this.

Comment: This is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/wB7fn/8/  Seems like the width of the main menu element needs to be at least as wide as the widest sub menu element.